# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property XXX of undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, semantic-ui

When i try to serve my application, after serving getting errors in the console like below, It's completely depends on angular-animate. How to fix this issue in angular..?
Can someone help me to fix this?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.onAnimationProgress (angular-animate.js:1324)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4737)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4549)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js:7807)
    at jQuery.fn.init.triggerHandler (jquery.js:7881)
    at semantic.min.js:16506
```

I gone through angular-animate.js 1324 line and debugged every time ELAPSED_TIME_MAX_DECIMAL_PLACES this variable getting value to this variable but still getting undefined error.

```
 var elapsedTime = parseFloat(ev.elapsedTime.toFixed(ELAPSED_TIME_MAX_DECIMAL_PLACES));
```

Here is the code which i have doing animation,

```
restore: {
             conditions: function() {
               var
                 animation = module.get.currentAnimation();
               if (animation) {
                 $module
                   .removeClass(animation);
                 module.verbose('Removing animation class', module.cache);
               }
               module.remove.duration();
             }
           },

           add: {
             failSafe: function() {
               var
                 duration = module.get.duration();
               module.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                 $module.triggerHandler(animationEnd);
               }, duration + settings.failSafeDelay);
               module.verbose('Adding fail safe timer', module.timer);
             }
           },

           remove: {
             animating: function() {
               $module.removeClass(className.animating);
             },
             animationCallbacks: function() {
               module.remove.queueCallback();
               module.remove.completeCallback();
             },
             queueCallback: function() {
               $module.off('.queue' + eventNamespace);
             },
             completeCallback: function() {
               $module.off('.complete' + eventNamespace);
             },
```

It's been trigger on this line,

> $module.triggerHandler(animationEnd);

Thanks,

Comment: No answer here just ideas to narrow it down: The only time toFixed is used (in all of angularJS) is here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/e5c6174839e96113c93913dd8b3c4cca760dfc41/src/ngAnimate/animateCss.js#L820 So first I'd look at places where you use $animateCss directly or places with css-classes `ng-<event>` (enter, leave, move) which uses $animateCss under the hood and see what values you pass in. I'm not sure what could cause the error. Maybe if you are deleting some element that is being animated? (if so, stop the animation first)

Comment: Do a `console.log(ev.elapsedTime)` in order to see what's the value of `ev.elapsedTime` since it seems to be `undefined` as the error states.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jaccs TransitionEvent / AnimationEvent has poor IE-support. I sure hope (!) this isn't a browser issue?

Comment: Mixing jQuery with the AngularJS framework is asking for grief. And adding semantic-ui may make it worse. I am voting to close this question as of topic because questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg edited the question and updated with supposed code which i used animated.

Answer (score -1):

you can try bellow

```
var elapsedTime = parseFloat(parseFloat( ev.elapsedTime).toFixed(ELAPSED_TIME_MAX_DECIMAL_PLACES));
```

convert your variable into float to use toFixed() method